# Need some advice for a voltage clamp for motor controllers

Tags: motor-controller, supercapacitor

I'm working on a project that is powered by a 12V 100A PC power supply in line with 5 x 2.7V 350F supercapacitors. There are three 2x30A motor controllers driving wormgear DC motors. The supercapacitors are there for transient overcurrent beyond what the power supply can handle. I've been through a different of iterations with this board addressing different issues as they come up.

After a stalled motor sent a motor controller up in smoke I realized I need some better protection in place so I'm putting a 500A relay/contactor in place so that I can directly cut power to the motor controllers if needed.

I'm looking for help with two related pieces. First I need a voltage clamp (there's one on the motor controller but I want it separate) that will compare 12V from the power supply to the voltage coming from the motor controllers which can shootup in the case of regen.

The second would be a similar op-amp or comparator that would be used if voltage continues to rise above what the voltage clamp can handle that could be sent to a MOSFET to shutoff the 500A relay and directly cut power to the motor controllers.

I have an Arduino included for monitoring the supercaps. Maybe it could be used to control the MOSFETs instead of a comparator? I would need something like an optoisolator (possible?) to read the 12V signal and the voltage of the motor controllers. [image]

Comment: Why don't you use current control?

Comment: Ahem, workgear motors are noted for their inability to be back driven and hence regen is largely impossible.

Comment: The motor control doesn't do current limiting, how would that be done? When these wormgear motors brake without diodes or voltage clamp they are shutting off the power supply.